# How to display test data received from server in Android

Tags: android, multithreading, user-interface, client

I am writing an app that involves Client -> Server -> Client communication (one way traffic). I have my data transmitted from client A to the server, simple to test, just print to console, however, I'm trying to test to see if the data has been sent on to the next client. I have tried a text view, nothing is displaying in this view however, now I don't know if that's because the data hasn't arrived or indeed because I've coded it wrong. I'm not very experienced in android.

I've attached my code below, if anyone can help I would really appreciate it.

Regards, 
Gary

```
public class Parent extends Activity {

private Socket s;
private PrintWriter p;
String location;
double Platitude, Plongitude;
double Clatitude, Clongitude;
double distance;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)

{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.parent);

    Thread rec = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try { 

                s = new Socket("192.168.1.2", 1980);

                InputStream fromServer = s.getInputStream();

                while (s.isConnected()) {

                    Scanner r = new Scanner(fromServer);

                    if(r.hasNextLine())
                    {
                        location = r.nextLine();
                    }

                    TextView myTextview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dist);
                    myTextview.setText(location);

                }

            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    rec.start();       
}
```

Comment: why `location = r.nextLine()`? has it to be the last one or just add a += ?

Comment: well there should only be one line really, coordinates of client a are found, sent to server and onto client b, I'm just setting string location to the next line that is received by the scanner..